# How to edit HTML in wordpress backend

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using the "Avada" theme in WordPress. I would like to make small changes in the mobile menu, any ideas on how can I edit it. I know in WordPress backend I can only find PHP files that are generating HTML.

In the following screenshot, I would like to move the button tag above a tag. Any ideas would be great.

[image: HTML]

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045111/how-to-edit-the-html-code-in-wordpress-theme

Comment: You should create a child theme, and then create the file relative to the parent theme that holds your modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and do what @[Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922522/justin) said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220273/how-can-i-reorder-my-divs-with-css).

Code here:

```css
#flex { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
#a { order: 2; }
#b { order: 1; }
#c { order: 3; }
```

```html
<div id="flex">
   <div id="a">A</div>
   <div id="b">B</div>
   <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```

To edit within Avada follow this path:

Dashboard > Avada > Theme Options > Custom CSS

Enter your relevant css in there:

```
.fusion-bar-heighlight {
//Your CSS
}
```

Custom CSS entered here will override the theme CSS. In some cases, the !important tag may be needed